# Need to store 16 bytes in java.Which datatype i should use and how

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, data-structures, types

I need to store 16 bytes in java.

How can i do the same.

**Issue :**

```
M = D || I
```

Here `D` would be 8 bytes, `I` would be 8 bytes and `||` denotes concatenation

so `M` will be 128 bits or 16 Byte long.

How can i store `M` in java datatype?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a byte array ?

```
byte[] data = new byte[16];
```